# PIC: how to set timer0 to give an interrupt at every 1 sec?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, timer, interrupts

I am programming a PIC18F67K22 and I've set it to use a 16X4Mhz Internal RC oscillator with PLL enabled.

- High level interrupt on `TIMER0` overflow
- I am using MCC18 compiler.

**So how to set `TIMER0` to give an interrupt at every second?**

Comment: Give it a period that is slightly greater than 1s, then use CTC to tune it to 1s.

Comment: I am not understanding what are you saying.please can you explain in brief??

Comment: Do you understand how the timer modules work at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TIMER0` is a 16bits timer, so to set to interrupt every 1 second you need to set:

- **Prescaler @ 16**
- **TMR0 Preload @ 3036**

The equation:

$$T = \left(\frac{4}{Fosc}\right) \cdot Presc \cdot (Resolution - Preload)$$

Where:

- T = Period = 1s
- Fosc = Oscilator Frequency = 4MHz
- Presc = Prescaler = 16
- Resolution = 2<sup>16</sup> = 65535
- Preload = 3036

Sample code:

```
// Timer0 Registers:16-Bit Mode; Prescaler=1:16; TMRH Preset=$BD; 
//                  TMRL Preset=$DC; Freq=1,00Hz; Period=1,00 s
T0CON.TMR0ON = 1;  // Timer0 On/Off Control bit: 1=Enables Timer0 / 0=Stops Timer0
T0CON.T08BIT = 0;  // Timer0 8-bit/16-bit Control bit: 1=8-bit timer/counter / 0=16-bit timer/counter
T0CON.T0CS   = 0;  // TMR0 Clock Source Select bit: 0=Internal Clock (CLKO) / 1=Transition on T0CKI pin
T0CON.T0SE   = 0;  // TMR0 Source Edge Select bit: 0=low/high / 1=high/low
T0CON.PSA    = 0;  // Prescaler Assignment bit: 0=Prescaler is assigned; 1=NOT assigned/bypassed
T0CON.T0PS2  = 0;  // bits 2-0  PS2:PS0: Prescaler Select bits
T0CON.T0PS1  = 1;
T0CON.T0PS0  = 1;
TMR0H = $BD;        // preset for Timer0 MSB register
TMR0L = $DC;        // preset for Timer0 LSB register
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that an anonymous user had a comment regarding setting `T0CON.PSA = 0` instead of `T0CON.PSA = 1`. They attempted to [edit you answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/82163) instead of posting a comment to bring the issue to your attention, which was rejected. Their comment was the following, in case you can't access the link above: `PSA must be zero for the prescaler to be considered. This code functions improperly when this bit is set to 1.`